# I want to achieve 10000 rps when thread(user number)=10000 in JMeter, how can I achieve this target?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Which controller or timer I should use for controlling rps ?
Can you please let me know?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve 10000 RPS with 10000 threads (virtual users) **only if your application response time is 1 second**

- if your application response time is less than one second - you will get more RPS
- if your application response time is more than one second - you will get less RPS

There are 2 main per-requisities:

1. Your application has to be able to respond fast enough because if it is not capable of supporting 10k requests per second - no matter what you do you won't be able to reach the target throughput as JMeter waits for the response prior to starting the next request
2. JMeter has to be able to send requests fast enough so make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and it might be the case you will have to go for [distributed testing mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

The easiest way of conducting X requests per second load is using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) combination, both can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)